# Github pages code blocks behave differently offline and online

Tags: css, jekyll, github-pages

The offline version is the one I'd like to get and it looks like this:

[image]

The online version however looks like this:

[image]

Also, [this is the direct link](https://averdones.github.io/tensorflow-object-detection-star-wars/) to the blog so you can see the WRONG version.

As you can see, there is a dark gray box around the code block that I don't want to see. I've tried looking into the configuration files, but since I can see it properly offline, I don't know how to fix it.
I'm using jekyll 3.5.2.

[This](https://github.com/averdones/averdones.github.io) is the repository of the blog.

Comment: The web version seems to correct with regards to your github repository. `_highlights.scss` tells `.highlight` to have `margin: 20px 0 20px 0`. Both the `div` and the `pre` have a class called `.highlight` in the online version so the double margins are correct (with regards to the code I'm seeing) Without code provided by you I cannot be sure, but I think your local version has a slightly different SASS or HTML code. Synchronizing your repositories will help. Otherwise, maybe you're using different build tools for your code locally vs online? Please provide software and versions in that case.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I noticed that too. I just pushed my online version, so it should be the same as the offline. You can see all the code  in the repository that I linked in the post. I think the relevant code is in "style.scss" and in "/sass/_highlights.scss", but again, I'm not sure so it could be somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a ***Gemfile*** containing :

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
gem 'github-pages'
```

I'm able to reproduce Github pages behavior.

You can resolve your problem by replacing, in ***_highlights.scss***, the `.highlight {...` rule by a `pre.highlight {...` rule.